# How can the screen orientation be reset when moving from view B back to view A?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I have to 2 view controllers (A and B).  vc A is a list of items and it supports portrait only orientation.  You select an item from the list and are taken to vc B (via pushViewController), which displays details about the selected item.  vc B supports portrait as well as landscape view.

So, while vc B is being displayed, let's say the device is rotated to change the view to landscape - when the user goes back to vc A (via popViewController) - vc A will be displayed in landscape, which I don't want.  I want it to be displayed in portrait.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make A support portrait orientation only:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
}
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks!  I had a logic problem in A, it was supporting both landscape and portrait - I just didn't realize that until now.